# SAS 9.4 - Re-activate Results Viewer after ODS HTML CLOSE but suppress writing HTML Body File

Tags: sas, ods

When I need to export to Excel in SAS 9.4, I typically run a code like this:

```
ods html close;
ods html file="C:\folder\filename.xls";
ods html close;
ods html; /*with this I'm trying to send my output back to the results viewer once more*/
```

However, when I run the last ODS HTML to try to send to Results Viewer, the log displays the following message:

> "Writing HTML Body file: sashtml1.htm."

This makes the results show up in the Results Viewer but also creates a file on my computer (`sashtml1.htm`) in the folder with my SAS code. I don't want the output to save to my computer, I only want to view it in SAS. How should I code differently to accomplish this? I do not want to open and re-open SAS.

Comment: You really should be using ODS EXCEL to write XLSX files instead of creating an HTML file and using a phony extension to trick your PC into using Excel to open it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this next time I run the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close the original one. Just tell SAS not to send it anything.

```
ods html exclude all ;
```

When you open the second one give it an ID.

```
ods html (id=ForExport) file="C:\folder\filename.xls";
```

Then you can close the new one and reanimate the old one.

```
ods html (id=ForExport) close ;
ods html exclude none ;
```